# Why can you define function without parameter in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, partial-application

I have function add which I apply partially to create a new function addOne.

```
add :: Int -> (Int -> Int)
add x y = x + y
```

addOne can be defined with explicit parameter

```
addOne :: Int -> Int
addOne y = add 1 y
```

or without explict parameter

```
addOne :: Int -> Int
addOne = add 1
```

I have four questions:

1. Why can I define the new function without explicit parameter?
2. Is there any difference between these two definitions?
3. When do I know when I can define function without a parameter?
4. Which definition is preferred and when?

Comment: you should have a look at *curried functions* and *partial application*  : http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Currying

Comment: Consider the case `strTake :: Int -> String -> String`; `strTake = take`.  All this is doing is making an alias for `take` that only works on `String`s instead of any kind of list.  You don't need to define the parameters, you're just setting one value equal to another value.  Then you can consider something like `take5 :: [a] -> [a]`; `take5 = take 5`.

Comment: yet another tutorial: http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions

Comment: Note also that because `->` is right associative, `Int -> (Int -> Int)` is the same as `Int -> Int -> Int`. Unlike some other languages, there's no distinction between the two types in Haskell. As others have noted, whether you *implement* the function as an explicit lambda or not sometimes does make a difference for optimization or the monomorphism restriction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Because `addOne y = add 1 y` means `addOne = \y -> add 1 y`, and `\x -> f x` is always just `f`.  This is called eta equivalence.  So `addOne = add 1`.
2. No
3. Always.  Function parameters are just syntactic sugar for lambdas:

   ```
   add :: Int -> Int -> Int
   add = \x y -> x + y
   ```

   Whether you can remove the variable binding completely is a different matter.
4. It's always nice to "eta reduce" (that is, remove the rightmost bound variable in a function binding when it matches a function application in the bound expression) when you can, as it avoids introducing a superfluous name.

Comment: I will add that some editors support `hlint` integration, which is great for telling you when you can eta reduce, saving you the effort of having to find all those instances yourself.

Comment: Seconded, `hlint` is great for that.  Eta reduction is fun!

Comment: As for question 2, there is a difference to the GHC optimizer, but that's probably something we shouldn't confuse people with here.

Answer (score 4):

One of the basic concepts in functional programming that you'll need to learn to use Haskell is that *functions are just a kind of value, definitions just name things*.  It's not like procedural languages where there's a sharp distinction made between *functions* and *variables* and function definitions are completely different from variable definitions.

So a variable definition like

```
addOne :: Int -> Int
addOne = add 1
```

is just adding a name for the expression `add 1`, so you can refer to it as `addOne`.  It's identical to a variable declaration.[1]  The fact that the value of that variable is a function is almost incidental, from Haskell's perspective.

Your `add` definition:

```
add :: Int -> (Int -> Int)
add x y = x + y
```

is also a variable definition.  It's a bit of syntax sugar Haskell provides for:

```
add :: Int -> Int -> Int
add = \ x -> \ y -> x + y
```

on the theory that it's easier to read.  But it's still just sugar; you never need it (except see [1] below) like you would in other languages.

[1]: The [dreaded monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction) also comes into play here.  The idea is just: in a function definition, the RHS will be executed by the computer many times (as many times as you call the function).  You are probably aware of this from other languages.  In a monomorphic variable definition, the RHS will be executed at most once, which is also similar to how other languages work.  However, a polymorphic variable often ends up acting like a function definition, with the RHS being executed as many times as the value of the variable is accessed.  So Haskell dis-allows polymorphic definitions unless you have a polymorphic type signature (so you say "I know what I'm doing, allow this variable to be polymorphic") or you have arguments on the left-hand side (so it "looks like" the RHS should be executed many times).